# Putting text in a repeat without repeating the text

Tags: lilypond, repeats

I want to put text in a `\repeat unfold` in LilyPond without repeating the text, so that it only shows up on the first instance of the phrase.

I can't put it on the previous note because the repeat phrase is the start of the piece.
When I put it on a note in the repeat expression, the text appears above both instances of the note.
I've also tried using a spacing rest, but the duration of the invisible rest is added to the already full measure and causes other problems.

Is there a way to make the text not repeat with the note?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the text into a parallel music passage that doesn't use `\repeat`, for example

```
{ \new Staff {
  << { \repeat unfold 3 { c''4 d'' } }
     { s4^"foo" s4^"bar" }
  >>
  e'' f''
} }
```

It doesn't matter that the parallel passages are different lengths, as the example demonstrates.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since LilyPond version 2.23, there are a new some new commands for repeats.  The `\volta` command goes inside of a `\repeat` (`unfold`, `volta`, or `segno`) and specifies a musical expression that is applied to a particular iteration of the repeat loop.

To have only-markup as the musical expression, the trick is to attach the markup to a spacer with zero duration:

```
\repeat unfold 3 {
    \volta 1 { s1*0^\markup "text" }
    c'4 d' e' f'
}
```

See: [1.4.1 Long repeats - Other variation in repeated sections](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/long-repeats#other-variation-in-repeated-sections) for more detail.